# Python - How to launch a subprocess before exiting the program (which is running on a detached screen)?

Tags: python, linux, subprocess, gnu-screen

For some reason, I would like to launch a script just before exiting my current one. I found one simple way to do it:

script1.py:

```
#**
#some code
#**
p=subprocess.Popen(["python", "script2.py"])
```

With this, if I run script1, it will launch script2 at the end just before exiting.

However if I run script1 within a screen (screen python script1.py), the screen will terminate before script2 has even a chance to start.

Moreover, since script2 is very long, I would like not to wait that it ends before exiting script1. Is there a way to do it? Maybe by launching script2 in another screen? If so how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the second script and then wait for it to complete

```
p=subprocess.Popen(["python", "script2.py"])
p.wait()
```

or more elegantly you can use `os.execv` that will replace your python interpreter by the new one (the PID will stay unchanged, you'll keep the console).

```
os.execv("/usr/bin/python", ["/usr/bin/python", "script2.py"])
```

Comment: I like your os.execv idea, but if I understood the function it won't execute anything after the subprocess call in script1? For example if I have things like `print "script2 has been launched"` just after the subprocess call and before the exiting of script1, they won't be executed?

Comment: That's it, the message will not be printed: Your process will die and be replaced by the new one, nothing after this system call will be executed.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I'm looking for, I'll just run before this the few things I wanted to run after and that'll do it!